Error legal version should look like 'x.x.x.x' while creating .msi package using Wix toolset
My project is using Wix Toolset to create .msi file.
While building the MSI file it is showing below error.
C:\projects\ABCInstallerW35.wxs(8):  error CNDL0108: The Product/@Version attribute's value, '4205', is not a valid version.  Legal version values should look like 'x.x.x.x' where x is an integer from 0 to 65534.


Where is it validating this version pattern. I searched a lot but I didn't find any such validation in .wxs or .wixproj or any other file.
Can anyone please help where can I fix this? I want to remove his x.x.x.x version pattern.
Tried to search in .wxs and .wixproj file and didn't find anything there which can fix it.

The validation is done for the Version attribute of the Product element (most likely in Product.wxs). Since Windows Installer (msi) defines the format of the product version as Major.Minor.Patch I think that there is no way around this.
ProductVersion property
